# CLLocation not showing accurate result

Tags: objective-c, swift, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am working on an offline application where I have to show user travelled path and I am using MKMapview for this. Whenever I am getting the CLLocation coordinate from didUpdateLocations method it is showing  un satisfactory results bcoz if user location is on the road then it was showing some meter away location let say building location and when I draw the complete user travelled path then that path will cross so many buildings but user have travelled on road not on the building. So is there any way where we can correct this location coordinate (without using internet) so that it will show exact location.

If there is no way to do this then how any other taxi app is showing driver current location on the road. I don't want to use Google Map for this.

Comment: Are you using kCLLocationAccuracyBest?

Comment: Yes,
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

Comment: Then you can try kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation.. or you can read this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1197775/3108877

Comment: @Rroobb- This Doen't resolves my problem

Answer (score 0):

Location Manager is going to return more than one locations. You may add some code to check if the location returned is good enough for you. Here is an example:

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
{
    if([locations lastObject].horizontalAccuracy <= (some number) )
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: I am already using this code in my app

 if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }


I am using the Location age validation too.
 NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (locationAge > 6.0)
    {
        return;
    }